# When I try to use image_picker in my flutter project I got an incompatibility error with AndroidX

Tags: android, flutter

I set image_picker: 0.5.0+ and I got this error.

> WARNING: This version of image_picker will break your Android build if
>   it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
>            See ***a link***.
>            This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
>            ********************************************************* FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I tried to set these properties in gradle:

> android.useAndroidX=true
>
> android.enableJetifier=true

but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I change image_picker from 0.5.02 to 0.4.12 and it works!

Actually, image_picker's docs says that now it uses AndroidX instead of deprecated original Android Support Library about 0.5.0+ version

[image_picker_0.5.0 breaking change](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker#050)